# Minecraft Realms Purchase

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

My parent agreed to purchase Realms server. A friend of mine created a Minecraft world and we have been playing that world for quite a while now. Since I'm on mobile, I cannot think of and find a way to download his world and turn it into my own Realm server. I had an idea and decided to create a dummy account with the Realm purchased so that he can have access to it and make it into a realm server. My only concern is that can my friend have access to my parent's bank account? When I press purchase Realm with that dummy account, one the payment methods include my parent's account and that's what I decide to use. Is it safe to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the payment information is saved to the **device** you purchase the Realms server on, it's safe. **Minecraft will not save the payment information** beyond the final four digits of the credit card, which isn't enough to purchase anything - they don't have any access to their bank account. The only thing your friend could do is not cancel the Realms server subscription.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the last statement, so my friend can prevent the cancellation of the subscription?

Comment: @Kaiphomy Yes, simply by choosing not to cancel it - however, as your parent has control of the card, they can call their bank and stop the payments happening at all.

Comment: Okay thanks for the information.